# Gerrit build with bazel: maven2 jar sh1 not match

Tags: bazel, gerrit

ERROR: /home/builder/gerrit-3.2.14/lib/bouncycastle/BUILD:3:13: //lib/bouncycastle:bcprov depends on @bcprov//jar:jar in repository @bcprov which failed to fetch. no such package '@bcprov//jar': failed [/usr/bin/python3, /home/builder/gerrit-3.2.14/tools/download_file.py, "-o", /home/builder/.cache/bazel/_bazel_builder/9afd9023b67c60c8c3f995a3b1c75370/external/bcprov/jar/bcprov-jdk15on-1.61.jar, "-u", "MAVEN_CENTRAL:/org/bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on/1.61/bcprov-jdk15on-1.61.jar", "-v", "00df4b474e71be02c1349c3292d98886f888d1f7"]: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on/1.61/bcprov-jdk15on-1.61.jar:
expected 00df4b474e71be02c1349c3292d98886f888d1f7
received 8f13ba4527c222db2995b9cf052d88a4540890f9

Comment: Can you provide more details and reproduction steps to reproduce the above error.

Comment: My build environment is Ubuntu 14.04.6, Python v3.4.3, java 8, nodejs v8.9.3,  apache/2.4.7, Maven 3.0.5

I use "bazel build release" to build gerrit.

Comment: I download gerrit code from "https://github.com/GerritCodeReview/gerrit",
then install bazel according to "https://docs.bazel.build/versions/0.24.0/install-ubuntu.html".